# VB.Net Windows Form Databinding

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I am trying (novice) to create a simple app that users can update a data table in a sql database via by adding, deleting or updating current records.  So I have created the form and have combo box in there that is connected to a data table in my database.  I want to load the value of the record selected into that combo box, but also have the list of options available to update that record in the database.  the problem with my code is, it has the correct corresponding value for the record, but it is not showing.  Also, when I select the combo box, the other values in the table are not there. the value is duplicated 2 times.

Here is how the combo box is bound:

[image]

How it Loads:

[image: How It loads]

When I select the combo box:

[image: When I select the cmbox]

```
  Public Sub FillDriverDataSet()      
    Dim sql As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dv = New DataView(ds.Tables("Drivers"))
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim cm As CurrencyManager


    sql = "SELECT * FROM tCommercialDrivers where id = 23"
    OpenConnection()

    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)

    Dim drivers As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    drivers.Fill(ds, "Drivers")
    dv = New DataView(ds.Tables("Drivers"))
    cm = CType(Me.BindingContext(dv), CurrencyManager)
    bs.DataSource = dt


    adapter.Fill(dt)

    drpRouteType.DataSource = dt
    drpRouteType.DisplayMember = "RouteType"
    drpRouteType.ValueMember = "RouteType"

    txtRoute.DataBindings.Clear()
    txtRoute.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "RouteID")

  End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like youre going round in circles a bit with all those datasets. You're also mixing data access methods, with all that "SQL string in a button click handler" as well as your datatables. You should be doing this with your datasets and tableadapters only, but it's not immediately clear how much of a tangle you've got in with it all. If you can consider posting the entire project it'd help to take a look

Comment: Ok so after reading your note, i cleaned up the code (I think) and it works

Answer (score 0):

As an overview of how this is supposed to work ( and bearing in mind that I can't see your database structure so I'm guessing at it a bit)

- open connection manager
- add a connection to sql server
- create a new DataSet type item in the project
- open the DataSet

  - drag eg the CommercialDrivers table out of connection manager and into the DataSet then right click the table adapter and choose configure , or
  - right click the DataSet and choose add tableadapter, configure the connection, choose "select that retrieves rows.."
- add or modify (depending what you did above) the sql so it's `SELECT * FROM commercialDrivers WHERE iD = @DriverId`
- call your method FillById and GetDataById
- finish
- repeat true above process for the table that holds the RouteTypes but because we don't be selecting them singly, do not add a where clause and leave the default names of Fill and GetData
- you should now have a DataSet with two tables and possibly a datarelation line between them. The relation isn't strictly necessary for our needs and can be removed
- make a new form and open it
- open the datasources window on the view menu (other windows)
- from datasources drag the routetypes node to the form, then delete the grid view and bindingnavigator that appeared - keep the other stuff that appeared as it will be useful
- rename the DataSet in the bottom tray so that it's called something else (anything; we just want the instance name to be different from the type name as it can cause confusion to have a variable named the same as a type. I prefix the name with an underscore, tableadapters too)
- in the data sources window click the drop down next to CommercialDrivers and change it to Details mode, expand the node, change RouteType to a combobox
- drag the CommercialDrivers parent node to the form, a bunch of controls will appear, with data bindings already set to the DataSet on the form
- for the route type combo get its properties:

  - change dropdownstyle to dropdownlist
  - change DataSource to be routetypesbindingsource
  - change displaymember to be whatever is the route type text column
  - change valuemember to be whatever column holds the route type id
  - in the (data bindings) node at the top of the properties grid check that selectedvalue is bound to CommercialDrivers.RouteTypeId (CommercialDrivers binding source, datamember route type id), and remove the binding from the text property. Combos with a backing list should have selectedvalue bound, not text

That's it; the one line of code you have to write or sort out is filling the CommercialDriver table with the relevant ID. Technically it's probably zero lines; Visual studio probably already did that for you by putting a bindingnavigator complete with textbox and fill Button when you dragged the details into the form but you might want to change how it's done. The route types table in the DataSet is filled in form load, with all the different route types, the combo will read eg commercial drivers table's routetypeid value of 4, look up that value in the column set in its value member (in the route types table set in its DataSource) and show the value it finds in the column set in its displaymember. If you change the combo to something else it gets the value from the new row (From the column set in the valuemember) and writes that value into the commercialdrivers table routetypeid hence changing the routetype for that driver

It looks a lot when written down (and if you get stuck at any point let me know; I wrote this from memory, without a visual studio in front of me, on a cellphone so there may be some detail I forgot) but in reality when you're used to the process it probably takes about a minute to do this. VS writes all the code you did - you can see it in the various .Designer files if you're interested

Answer (score -1):

So I cleaned it up a bit, and it works now.  Let me know if you still see something I could have done better.  Thank you for your reply!

Public Sub FillDriverDataSet()
Dim sql As String

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dv = New DataView(ds.Tables("Drivers"))
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim cm As CurrencyManager


    sql = "SELECT * FROM tCommercialDrivers where id = 26"
    OpenConnection()

    Dim drivers As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)

    drivers.Fill(ds, "Drivers")
    dv = New DataView(ds.Tables("Drivers"))
    cm = CType(Me.BindingContext(dv), CurrencyManager)

    drpRouteType.DataBindings.Clear()
    drpRouteType.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "RouteType")


    txtRoute.DataBindings.Clear()
    txtRoute.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "RouteID")

    txtDriverID.DataBindings.Clear()
    txtDriverID.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "DriverID")

    txtEmailAddress.DataBindings.Clear()
    txtEmailAddress.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "EmailAddress")

    txtDriverName.DataBindings.Clear()
    txtDriverName.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "DriverName")

    txtDollYd.DataBindings.Clear()
    txtDollYd.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "YardageAmt")

    txtDayRate.DataBindings.Clear()
    txtDayRate.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "DayRate")

    cbxActive.DataBindings.Clear()
    cbxActive.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dv, "IsActive")

    cbxIncentive.DataBindings.Clear()
    cbxIncentive.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dv, "IncentivePay")

    ' dteExpDate.DataBindings.Clear()
    'dteExpDate.DataBindings.Add("text", dv, "ExperienceDate")


End Sub
```

Comment: What's the use of that `CurrencyManager`? + You're filling a single DataTable, so fill a DataTable, not a DataSet + The DataView is not needed, use just the DataTable's Column name for the binding. It's probably better to assign the DataTable to a BindingSource which you can store as a Field, in case you need to filter, sort or whatever else, then use this object for the bindings.

Comment: With this code you're still probably buying a dog and barking yourself; if you're using tableadapters your code shouldn't ever really need any mention of: "SQL in a string", a dataadapter, bindings.anything, currencymanager...

Comment: It should be approximately 1 line of code from you, and all the rest of it is hidden away in the formx.Designer.cs and written with a few of mouse clicks